# JSON response returning null

Tags: android, json, encoding

I am currently working on a french Android application, and the JSON response is returning null when I have an accent like (é) or (è) in it. How can I avoid this please? Can anybody help me to solve my problem please? This is my code:

```
public class JSONParserList
{
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParserList() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
{
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSONList", json);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Parse the string to a JSON object
    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage() + "] " + json);
    }

    // Return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You are using UTF-8 so accented characters are not the problem. Does your system respond well for other inputs ?

Comment: Yes no problem with other input without accents

Comment: If you have access to the server code then can you try and return the error/exceptions that were faced when processing the input at the server side. That will really help you to debug the problem quickly.

Comment: There is no error in the server. The word (élément) is saved correctly in database. But in Android, it's returning null

Comment: I probably figured out the error, use "UTF8" and not "UTF-8" as shown here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html...

Comment: It also return null :/

Answer (score 0):

Since your client parser is hard-coded to expect UTF-8 encoded data, I'd double-check to server payload response and verify charset is in fact UTF-8 encoded.

- Tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) are handy for inspecting response payloads.
- Inspect your response by going to the hex view.  é should map to  **c3 89**.
- Also verify the charset encoding which should be:

  ```
   Content-Type   application/json; charset=utf-8
   or
   Content-Type   text/html; charset=UTF-8
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

To

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```